# How to split data into training/testing sets using IFELSE for "PimaIndiansDiabetes" with multiple probabilities?

Tags: r, if-statement

I have this R minimum working environment using the PimaIndianDiabetes to work with.

```
  #load required library
  library(mlbench)
  #load Pima Indian Diabetes dataset
  data(PimaIndiansDiabetes)
  #set seed to ensure reproducible results
  set.seed(42)
  #split into training and test sets
  PimaIndiansDiabetes[,train] <- ifelse(runif(nrow(PimaIndiansDiabetes))
  <0.8,1,0)
  #separate training and test sets
  trainset <- PimaIndiansDiabetes[PimaIndiansDiabetes$train==1,]
  testset <- PimaIndiansDiabetes[PimaIndiansDiabetes$train==0,]
  #get column index of train flag
  trainColNum <- grep(“train”,names(trainset))
  #remove train flag column from train and test sets
  trainset <- trainset[,-trainColNum]
  testset <- testset[,-trainColNum]
  #get column index of predicted variable in dataset
  typeColNum <- grep(“diabetes”,names(PimaIndiansDiabetes))
```

My immediate problem is to split the data to training and test set with IFELSE function with probabilities as specified in the R code.

Answer (score 1):

There was a mistake in

```
PimaIndiansDiabetes[,train] <- ifelse(runif(nrow(PimaIndiansDiabetes))
                                  <0.8,1,0)
```

The ifelse works fine:

```
ifelse(runif(nrow(PimaIndiansDiabetes))
                                      <0.8,1,0)
```

but you have to use a string to assign a new column ('train' instead of train)

```
PimaIndiansDiabetes[,'train'] <- ifelse(runif(nrow(PimaIndiansDiabetes))
                                      <0.8,1,0)
```

Next thing that did not work was the selection of the 'trainColNum' you can either do it like this

```
trainColNum <- which(colnames(PimaIndiansDiabetes) == 'train')
```

or you use the dplyr package to remove the column

```
library(dplyr)
trainset <- trainset %>% select(-train)
testset <- testset %>% select(-train)
```

Same for the diabetes column

```
typeColNum <- which(colnames(PimaIndiansDiabetes) == 'diabetes')
```

Comment: can you please point out the problem for me in 
      PimaIndiansDiabetes[,train] <- ifelse(runif(nrow(PimaIndiansDiabetes))
                                  <0.8,1,0)

Comment: I edit my answer. There was only an error if you try to use the variable train to assign the new column, but the string 'train'